# express fileupload -- req.files is always undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I use postman to test this service and no matter what I do my `req.files` is always undefined. Body type is binary and I'm uploading xlsx file. Content-Type was auto set to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` by postman and I changed it to `multipart/form-data` and still req.files is undefined.

My app code:

```
var XLSX = require('xlsx');
var request = require('request');
const util = require('util');
var inspect = require('eyes').inspector({maxLength: false})
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

app.use(fileUpload());


app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);
  if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
  }

  // The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
  let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;

  // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
  sampleFile.mv('/uploads', function(err) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(500).send(err);

    res.send('File uploaded!');
  });
});
const PORT =  9999;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

Node version is 14.15.4

Package versions:

```
excel2json@1.0.0 /var/excel2json
├── express-fileupload@1.3.1
├── express@4.17.3
├── eyes@0.1.8
├── isarray@0.0.1 extraneous
├── multer@1.4.4
├── readable-stream@1.1.14 extraneous
├── request@2.88.2
├── string_decoder@0.10.31 extraneous
├── util@0.12.4
└── xlsx@0.18.5
```

postman version is latest

OS is Ubuntu LTS